# convert nested object in parent / children structure js

Tags: javascript, tree

I try to convert this structure (each child is property in object):

```js
const tree = {
  "Parent 1" : {
    "Children1": {
      "Children2": {
          "#1": { info: {}},
          "#2": { info: {}}.
          "#3": { info: {}}
    },
    "Children1-1": {
      "Children2-2": {
          "#1": { info: {}},
          "#2": { info: {}}.
          "#3": { info: {}}
    }
  },
  "Parent 2": {
  ...
   }
};
```

In to this tree structure with parent child view. But in the end of my tree i don't need childrens

```js
const resultTeee = [
  {
    name: 'Parent 1',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Children 1',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Children 2',
            children: [
              {name: "#1", info: {}},
              {name: "#2", info: {}}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Children 1-1',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Children 2-2',
            children: [
              {name: "#1", info: {}},
              {name: "#2", info: {}}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Parent 2'
    ....
  }
]
```

I try "traverse tree" approach but can't understand how to switch for new children path. Object can have **multiple nested structure** on each level.

Comment: What is `rep: {}`?

Comment: Regarding your edit: Every key-value pair is converted to an object. So, why is it not `{name: "#1", children: [{ name: 'info', children: [] }]}`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const toArrayTree = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        return {name: key, children: [toArrayTree(obj[key])]}
    })
}
```

object for testing

```
const tree = {
    "Parent 1" : {
        "Children1": {
            "Children2": {
                "#1": { info: {}},
                "#2": { info: {}},
                "#3": { info: {}},
            }
        },
    },
    "Parent 2" : {
        "Children2.1": {
            "Children2.2": {
                "#4": { info: {}},
                "#5": { info: {}},
                "#6": { info: {}},
            }
        },
    },
};
```

But as @adiga said, why the last branch of tree is not `{ name: 'info', children: [] }`?

### Update on solution

```
const toArrayTree = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        return typeof obj[key] === 'object' ?
            {name: key, children: [toArrayTree(obj[key])]} :
            {name: key, [key]: obj[key]};
    })
}
```

It's really bad idea to use  `Object(v) === v`, because it would be true for v being function for example

Comment: so in the end i need to change data structure

Comment: @NickMedvik it's kinda hard to detect when you need to stop from converting. I guess you can add some if statement/ternary operator for checking key name and if its name is "info" and its value is object - there is no need to convert. There's need to do so, because last object may have properties, I guess. Or is it always empty object?

Comment: @NickMedvik the recursion termination logic is not clear from question. If `info: { count: 10 }` is the `info` object, what would the output look like?

Comment: @NebSehemvi it's object with properties. So i need this separation for different logic in UI.

Comment: @NebSehemvi levels of object can be more than 1. I have edited example

Comment: @NickMedvik I guess you didn't get my point: algorithm itself is recursive, and because of that, ```"#3": { info: {}}``` will become ```[{ name: '#3', children: [{name: 'info', children: []}] }]}, no matter how deep is your last object branch. You can't say "stop before that branch and leave this last nested object as it is", unless some stop-parameter is provided. Though I can give you a bit better than adiga's solution (check my Update on solution)

Comment: @NebSehemvi, Thank you so much. I updated your algoritm for my case and it works